# How to refactor big class that has dependencies with so many other classes?

Tags: architecture, clean-architecture

I have designed class that has dependencies with so many other classes
BigClass has direct association with A, B, C, D and indirect dependency with E, F, G H, I.
According to Clean Architecture Chapter 10 ISP(Interface segregation principle), my BigClass seems to needs improvement.

[image]

So I redesign this using interface so that the dependencies are inverted like below

[image]

Am I doing right from the perspective of good design?
Is there any other suggestions?

Comment: There is nothing at all wrong or bad with a class having a dependency on 4 other classes, despite what you might think.  Yes, I agree that coding to an interface as you are suggesting in the second diagram is the correct approach.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Thanks for comment. BigClass has 4 director dependencies, but if you count indirect dependencies of successive classes it will soon have dependencies with more than 20~30 other classes. I worried about that.

Comment: Welcome to enterprise software, and this is either common or even expected.  Bad class design is not OK; having dependencies that you need is not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: @myoldgrandpa First question to ask in such cases is what's the actual problem/risk that you expect/hope such refactoring to solve/preempt.

Comment: @dxiv If class E is changed, class A and Big Class should be re-compiled when we use c++ like language. Big Class has many dependencies so it is too unstable. This kind of dependency is explained in Clean Architecture Chapter 10 ISP.

Comment: @myoldgrandpa What does "*direct association*" mean in the question, and what do the arrows indicate? If the *implementation* of an interface changes, clients of that interface would not normally need to be recompiled. If, on the other hand, the interface itself changes (in a binary incompatible way) then clients that use it must unavoidably be rebuilt.

Comment: @dxiv Direct association means BigClass has class A as it's member variable in the first diagram. Second diagram shows that BigClass has not class A but interfaceA so it has no compile dependency unless it's interface is changed as you said.

Comment: @myoldgrandpa An interface is generally used to formalize a contract. In this case, if I follow it right, you would be introducing an interface more as a convenience to decouple some modules and dependencies. There is nothing wrong with that per se, but it's a judgment call to be made based on each particular context. An interface is an extra layer that requires its own maintenance and testing, and can also add certain runtime overhead. Again, nothing wrong with that, but it's not an automatic call.

Comment: At the time when the principle was created, there were no test double techniques or libraries. Therefore, testing was made possible by using Interface. Now, with the development of useful mock libraries, the principle is no longer necessary. I believe it even has the potential for cargo cult programming.

Comment: @rysh According to my view, ISP was not only for the ease of testability. When you distribute software includes many modules, you are happier if you release as less modules as you can. In addition, you can save compile time for that. Is there any reason you think that ISP is for the testability ?

Comment: I'm sorry. I misunderstood. Mr. myoldgrandpa is right, there is no relationship between ISP and testability.
By the way, the benefit of compilation and distribution is certainly there if the implementation class and the class referring to it are separated into different modules. In this case, it didn't even say that the modules were split, so I assume they are in the same module, but can you still enjoy the benefits?